# Index.html not displaying after push from visual studio express

Tags: javascript, html, github

Haven’t uploaded html since 2017 to my github repo. I have a few Js projects already online that work

```
https://renovatio4ever.github.com/Profile
https://renovatio4ever.github.com/NeoProfile
```

These apparently work because they had an index.html page

I uploaded an index.html for the root of the .io repro and another new project (FutureGame) and it replies with 404 page not found. Waited 3 hours - nothing.

```
https://renovatio4ever.github.com/index.html (Fail, Error 404)
https://renovatio4ever.github.com/FutureGame/index.html (Fail, Error 404)
```

I read about _config.yml and Jekyll, but never had to use it i 2017. Is any of it now mandetory? If yes, any suggestions what I can do to get those index.html pages to work like in the “Profile” and “Neo Profile” Projects.

Here’s my _config entry for the root of my .io site directory.

```
permalink: https://renovatio4ever.github.io
name: renovatio4ever
theme: jekyll-theme-minimum
title: sad new site
description: a necessary bookmark
```

Again, I dont know if this .yml file is needed. If it is, i don’t know wgere it should live and get it functioning.

Huge Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rioV8 just had to rebuild all projects from scratcg persay so that it is compliant with Jekyll backend.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Since many of my projects were before 2016-2017 I decided to delete the entire project folder (including all 30 child projects and their htmls) from github, recreate the project, add .md’s to all my child html projects, and repush everything in my local repro. YmL, and Jekyll are happy again.

All my websites old and new now appear. Also, I now know to wait about 3-5 minutes for jekyll to complete its process behind the scenes before seeing any changes. Finally, to go to Actions (on github) to see progress of jekyll backend process.